# Security vulnerability Access Control: Database in sqlite insert

Tags: android, database, sqlite, insert, controls

Recently I received a report by Forify with many security issues about my Android application.
I dont understand one of them: Access Control: Database.
Details:

> BuicDAO.java, line 42 (Access Control: Database) Fortify Priority:
>   High Folder High Kingdom: Security Features Abstract: Without proper
>   access control, the method insert() in BuicDAO.java can execute a SQL
>   statement on line 42 that contains an attacker-controlled primary key,
>   thereby allowing the attacker to access unauthorized records.

Sink: 
BuicDAO.java:42

```
42 // synchronized(db)  
43 { 
44 myNewKEY = (int) this.db.insert("TableBUIC", null, values); 
45 } 
46 }
```

Here is my code:

BuicDAO.java

```
   public void insert()
   {
      int myNewKEY;      
      ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
      values.putNull("KEY");
      values.put("Name", "Me");
42    // synchronized(db)
43      {
44         myNewKEY = (int) this.db.insert("TableBUIC", null, values);
45      }
46   }
```

Which is the problem here?
I dont know what is the proper way to do safety inserts on Android/sqlite.

Comment: From what you've posted, looks like a false positive as there is no user-supplied data in the database operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary key is chosen by the database (because you set it to `NULL`), and using `ContentValues` prevents SQL injection attacks.

Fortify is just plain wrong.
And even a stupid computer algorithm could prove that your code is safe, so this is not just an overzealous warning, but a bug in Fortify.